# Remove item animation from Recycler View with scroll

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have some problem with animation on `RecyclerView`

I have chat list with lot of messages. Each message is removing with delay (20s) and animation fadeout(0.3s). All work fine but it look strange sometime. Because if message is removing then all item below going up during first item is removing (fadeout). It looks like cumulative views on first position.

I am thinking about start animation before remove item. But it is not good idea. Also I thought about combining removing animation with scrolling the removing view.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is animate/collapse the height of the item view from its full height to 0, then remove the item from the adapter and refresh after that animation is complete.

Comment: Yes. You are right. But problem is that views is resuabel by recycler view and I have realy lot of message and if I will use view with height 0 then will be similar problem

Comment: It's standard practice in a RecyclerView to reset all the properties of the views that might have changed since last used.  If you do this, you won't have any problems if you wait until *after* the animation completes before removing the item from the adapter.

Comment: Can you show me some example? I don't know if I completely understand you :)